# How to add more properties to resource in react-admin

Tags: react-admin

I'm working with reac-admin,
and according to the [demo](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/examples/demo) I have an index file for each resources.
for exampale this is my undex to organization resource:

```
import BusinessIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Business';
import { OrganizationCreate } from './OrganizationCreate';
import { OrganizationEdit } from './OrganizationEdit';
import { OrganizationList } from './OrganizationList';
import { OrganizationShow } from './OrganizationShow';

const resource = {
    list: OrganizationList,
    create: OrganizationCreate,
    edit: OrganizationEdit,
    show: OrganizationShow,
    icon: BusinessIcon,
};

export default resource;
```

Is it possible to add a custom actions to a resource, in addition to the list, create, edit and show?
I mean for example I want my resources to support also in print or in any other action.

something like:

```
  const resource = {
    list: OrganizationList,
    create: OrganizationCreate,
    edit: OrganizationEdit,
    show: OrganizationShow,
    print: OrgnaizationPrint,
    icon: BusinessIcon,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The resource allows to define components for predefined *routes*. If you want to add more components for routes not handled by react-admin, you probably want to override the `<Admin customRoutes>` prop.

To register your own routes, create a module returning a list of react-router-dom `<Route>` component:

```
// in src/customRoutes.js
import * as React from "react";
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Foo from './Foo';
import Bar from './Bar';

export default [
    <Route exact path="/foo" component={Foo} />,
    <Route exact path="/bar" component={Bar} />,
];
```

Then, pass this array as customRoutes prop in the `<Admin>` component:

```
// in src/App.js
import * as React from "react";
import { Admin } from 'react-admin';

import customRoutes from './customRoutes';

const App = () => (
    <Admin customRoutes={customRoutes} dataProvider={simpleRestProvider('http://path.to.my.api')}>
        ...
    </Admin>
);

export default App;
```

Taken from the react-admin documentation at https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#customroutes

Comment: Thank you! but how I can pass the props?
I add a custom routes  =
  <Route exact path="/organizations/:id/view" render={() =><OrganizationCard />} />

Comment: Checkout the react-router documentation